# Firefox SDK different panel per tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs, firefox-addon-sdk

Hi all this is my first Stack Overflow question, so be gentle.

I am trying to develop an addon with the Firefox SDK.  I have a button attached to a panel.  The panel intercepts certain web requests and displays them.

My problem is that the panel maintains it's state across all of my tabs and windows.  I would like each tab to have a panel with its own state.  This way, when I navigate between tabs, the panel will show the data relevant to that specific tab but not the other tabs.  I can't simply re-build the panel everytime I switch tabs because then the user would have to reload the page again for it to re-intercept the web requests.

I've been scouring the internet for the last two days trying to figure out how to do this and I can't even find a topic relevant to it.

If you need any more info/code snippets let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen of the hide and show events for the panel and send messages to the panel's content script that can adjust the content there. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fb6b727b8628c797e93b) for a basic example and of course read [the extensive panel documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel).

The best way to think about this is, the panel is a single-page web app. When the user clicks on the button, send the right signals to the panel's content script so it can display the correct things. When the user closes the panel or the panel is closed for some other reason, send in signals to clean up and 're-set' the panel.

If your code depends on a request out to some other site or service, what I would do is:

1. default state of panel is a 'Loading, please wait' message or animation
2. on opening the panel, make your requests and then emit a message to the panel's content script with whatever data it needs.
3. on closing the panel, emit a message that re-sets the panel back to the 'loading' state, so it is ready for the next time the panel is opened.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Here's how I ended up kind-of solving my problem.  In order to mimic panels with different state for different tabs, I have a javascript object with the key being the tabid.  On the "deactivate" event, I add the HTML from my panel to the object.  On the "activate" event, I check to see if the object contains any HTML for that tabid.  If it does, I use JQuery to replace the initial HTML.  Seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Yeah sure, in particular if you have specific static html mapped to each tab. Hard to tell without a lot of detail about your use case what the right answer is. :)